# iOS UI Automation - How can I locate all the UILabel in a UITableCell with accessibility attributes?

Tags: ios, testing, accessibility, instruments

I felt the accessibility attribute of an UI control is hard to understand during iOS UI Automation.
I have a table cell, which has many UILabel as children. I was intent to set the accessibility  labels for some UILabel in order to get their value in the test scripts.

What I expecated looked like:

```
        UIATableView "(null)" {{0, 64}, {320, 504}}
    elements: {
        UIATableCell 
        elements: {
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_TitleLbl" {{0, 99}, {320, 163}}
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_OrderStatusLbl" {{0, 99}, {320, 163}}
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_IdLbl" {{0, 99}, {320, 163}}
        }
        UIATableCell 
        elements: {
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_TitleLbl" {{0, 297}, {320, 163}}
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_IdLbl" {{0, 297}, {320, 163}}
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_OrderStatusLbl" {{0, 297}, {320, 163}}
        }
    }
```

But in fact I got:

```
        UIATableView "(null)" {{0, 64}, {320, 504}}
    elements: {
        UIATableCell "YIAllOrderCell_TitleLbl, YIAllOrderCell_OrderStatusLbl, YIAllOrderCell_IdLbl" {{0, 99}, {320, 163}}
        elements: {
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_TitleLbl, YIAllOrderCell_OrderStatusLbl, YIAllOrderCell_IdLbl" {{0, 99}, {320, 163}}
        }
        UIATableCell "YIAllOrderCell_TitleLbl, YIAllOrderCell_OrderStatusLbl, YIAllOrderCell_IdLbl" {{0, 297}, {320, 163}}
        elements: {
            UIAStaticText "YIAllOrderCell_TitleLbl, YIAllOrderCell_OrderStatusLbl, YIAllOrderCell_IdLbl" {{0, 297}, {320, 163}}
        }
    }
```

It seemed that Instruments treated all the UILabel controls in the table cell as a single UIAStaticText, that was not I expected.

Another confusion was that once I enable the accessibility for a UILabel, in automation scripts, its name would became the accessibility label, its value attribute return nothing.

With what I observed, the official document is ambiguous to me:

> UI Automation uses the accessibility label (if it’s set) to derive a name property for each element. Aside from the obvious benefits, using such names can greatly simplify development and maintenance of your test scripts.
>
> The name property is one of four properties of these elements that can be very useful in your test scripts.
>
> - name. Derived from the accessibility label
> - value. The current value of the control, for example, the text in a text field
> - elements. Any child elements contained within the current element, for example, the cells in a table view
> - parent. The element that contains the current element

Thanks a lot for anybody helping me to understand.